# How would I compress a 3-dimensional array in Lua?

Tags: lua

So, I have what is basically a three-dimensional array in Lua, really a voxel system. It looks like this:

```lua
  local VoxelTable = {
    [1] = { --X
      [5] = { --Y
        [2] = { --Z
          ["Type"] = "Solid",
          ["Rotation"] = "InverseX",
          ["Material"] = "Grass",
          ["Size"]     = Vector3.new(1,1,1) 
          --A 1x1x1 Solid grass block with rotation "InverseX"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The Voxels are generated, and because of that I can't compress them manually. But without compression rendering lags the game down a lot.

What I want to do is if there are three grass blocks right above/below eachother with the same rotation value, I combine them into one voxel, with a size of Vector3.new(1,3,1), with the position of the middle voxel.

So

```
[1] = { --X
  [5] = { --Y
    [2] = { --Z
      ["Type"] = "Solid",
      ["Rotation"] = "InverseX",
      ["Material"] = "Grass",
      ["Size"]     = Vector3.new(1,1,1) 
    }
  },
  [6] = { --Y
    [2] = { --Z
      ["Type"] = "Solid",
      ["Rotation"] = "InverseX",
      ["Material"] = "Grass",
      ["Size"]     = Vector3.new(1,1,1) 
    }
  },
  [7] = { --Y
    [2] = { --Z
      ["Type"] = "Solid",
      ["Rotation"] = "InverseX",
      ["Material"] = "Grass",
      ["Size"]     = Vector3.new(1,1,1) 
    }
  }
}
```

becomes

```
[1] = { --X
  [6] = { --Y
    [2] = { --Z
      ["Type"] = "Solid",
      ["Rotation"] = "InverseX",
      ["Material"] = "Grass",
      ["Size"]     = Vector3.new(1,3,1) 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a somewhat simplified example. I’ve created a 10 x 10 x 10 cube of voxels, giving each voxel a vec3 size attribute (as you have it) and a random letter attribute (a, b, or c). I then iterate over the voxels, looking up and down. If the voxel I’m on has the same letter attribute as the voxel above and below, then I set the above and below voxels to nil, and increase the size attribute of the middle voxel. I am sure this could all be optimized, and I’m sure more sophisticated logic could look for other voxel relationships besides this hard-coded stack-of-three identical voxels. But this is a start:

```
local world = {}
local letters = {"a", "b", "c"}

function setup()    
    -- Create simplified test data
    for x = 1, 10 do
        world[x] = {}

        for y = 1, 10 do
            world[x][y] = {}

            for z = 1, 10 do    
                world[x][y][z] = {}

                local randomIndex = math.random(1, 3)
                world[x][y][z].letter = letters[randomIndex]
                world[x][y][z].size = vec3(1, 1, 1)  
            end
        end
    end

    -- Combine common stacks of three
    for x = 1, 10 do
        for y = 2, 9 do -- Ensure there is at least a level below (y == 1) or above (y == 10)
            for z = 1, 10 do
                combineStacks(x, y, z)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

```
function combineStacks(x, y, z)
    local low = world[x][y - 1][z]
    local mid = world[x][y][z]
    local high = world[x][y + 1][z]

    if low ~= nil and mid ~= nil and high ~= nil then
        if low.letter == mid.letter and mid.letter == high.letter then
            world[x][y - 1][z] = nil -- low
            world[x][y + 1][z] = nil -- high

            mid.size = vec3(1, 3, 1)
            print("Stack of three identical voxels found!")
        end
    end
end
```

The above was written and tested (and visualized, shown below) in [Codea](https://codea.io). The vec3 construct is native to that environment and not to Lua in general, so keep that in mind.

Here’s a 2D visualization of the results, with each square showing a slice of the voxel cube. If you see a yellow point (representing a stack of three!), look at the square slice to the left and right, and at the same location you will see the voxels there are nil:

[image]